# Could not connect to hostapd (Ubuntu 18)?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint

I need to create a hostapt but I can't connect my phone to it, it stays **Connecting ...** forever and never connects I'm using **hostapd** in version **v2.6**, when executing the command `sudo hostapd ~ / Desktop / hostapd.conf -S` seems to run very well the host is created, all right but I can't connect this is my `hostapd.conf` file:

```
interface = wlp2s0b1
driver = nl80211
hw_mode = b
ssid = WifiTest
channel = 2

wpa = 2
wpa_passphrase = hello1234
wpa_key_mgmt = WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise = TKIP
rsn_pairwise = CCMP

macaddr_acl = 0
ignore_broadcast_ssid = 0
auth_algs = 1
```

But it doesn’t matter what I do doesn’t connect is `getting IP address` or`Connecting ...`forever, could someone help me?

Comment: b it too old, g or n depending on chipset for starters.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I modified the same thing more (I put 'n' and got an interface error: Configuration file: /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/hostapd.conf
Line 3: unknown hw_mode 'n'
1 errors found in configuration file '/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interface), my chipset is a BCM94313GMGB from Broadcom.